# Auto update form content

Tags: php, mysql

I want to achieve this: Submitting students scores onblur the form input field And these are my codes

Form.php

```
    <span id="ref_report"></span><br>
Student One:<input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' id='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin'id="admin" value='st1'><br>
Students Two  <input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' id='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin[]'id="admin" value='st2'><br>
Student  three  <input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' id='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin[]'id="admin" value='st3'><br>
```

//jquery

```
 $('#ref_no').blur(function(){
            var query_string = $(this).val();
            if(query_string.length>0)
            {
            //var filter = /^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{4,}$/;
            //if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()@#!?]+$/', $string) )
            var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9/#-]{1,}$/;// this allows special characters "/" and "-"
                if (!(filter.test(query_string))) {
                    $('#ref_report').html('<font color=red>This #Ref No. is not accepted</font>');
                    $('.login-apt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    return false;
                }
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "validate.php",
                    //data: query_string,
                    data: {ref_no:query_string},//ref_no

                    success: function(data)
                        {
                        if(data=='exist')
                        {
                            $('#ref_report').html('<font color=red><b>This #Ref. Number does not exist here</b></font>');
                            $('.login-apt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#ref_report').html('<img src=yes.png><font color="Green">Accepted</font>');
                            $('.login-apt').removeAttr('disabled',false);

                        }               
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

bellow are the php codes i used on the validat.php to do the trick:

```
if(isset($_POST['ref_no']))
{
    $ref_no = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['ref_no']));
    $admin = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['admin']));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_cms` WHERE `admin`= '$ref_no'";
    $myquery = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($myquery) !=0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery);

  for($i=0;$i< count($_POST['ref_no']); $i++){
     $data = $_POST['ref_no'][$i];
     $admin = $_POST['admin'][$i];

   $sql="INSERT INTO `tbl_cms` (`admin`, `content`) values('$admin', '" . $data . "')";
           mysql_query($sql);

           }

                echo 'not exist';

    }
    else
    {
            echo 'exist';

    }
}
```

I have a very simple MySQL table where I want the Scores for each students with their admin to automatically stored as key-in the score.It looks like that:

```
admin   Content
std1     3      
std2     5 
std3     6 
  .......................................................
```

My problem is that the code work but save only the content of the first form field i.e std1 score only. Instead of saving the scores of the three students and also the admin is not saving.
How to perfect this?

Comment: Don't give it to anyone and you'll be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

no client can access your php codes when viewing your website,but if you are installing your code in client's webserver(i don't recommend) then you can use php obfuscators or encoders.
i found these websites from the internet:

http://www.ioncube.com/

http://www.sourceguardian.com/

https://www.phpshield.com

http://www.obfusc.com/encoder_php.html

http://fopo.com.ar/

http://www.phpprotect.info/

http://www.codeeclipse.com/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side scripting language. Once you work with it you will know that the code will NOT show to others (client side).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to protect your php sources as they are not shown when the pages are accessed. Only the output of the script is visible.